# Merging two Arrays together

Tags: ruby

I have these two arrays

```
Hotel = 'hilton', 'marriot'
Price = '$350', '$375'
```

How would I go about merging the two arrays together and making the price a key to the hotel.

So when I access

```
Price[0]
```

It outputs

```
'$350' => 'hilton' (or however the correct output should be)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do as below using [`Array#zip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-zip) and [`Hash::[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) :

```
Hotel = 'hilton', 'marriot'
Price = '$350', '$375'
Hash[Price.zip(Hotel)]
# => {"$350"=>"hilton", "$375"=>"marriot"}
```

But to meet your posted description :

```
Hotel = 'hilton', 'marriot'
Price = '$350', '$375'
array_of_hash = Price.each_index.map { |i| { Price[i] => Hotel[i]} }
# => [{"$350"=>"hilton"}, {"$375"=>"marriot"}]
array_of_hash[0] # => {"$350"=>"hilton"}
```

Now choose, whatever way suits to your need.

Comment: `array_of_hash = Price.zip(Hotel).map {|a| Hash[*a] }` gets rid of the unsightly index.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That's nice too,

Comment: Since I only code for fun, I can afford to always choose aesthetics. In my never-ending quest to rid the world of indices, here's another (that creates two arrays and adds two statements): `hotel = Hotel.dup; price = Price.dup; Price.size.times.map { { price.shift => hotel.shift } }`
.